# Why am i getting infinite results? should'nt it show me only 1 clienti.ID_Cliente?

Tags: sql, ms-access

i need a query that takes in ID_Offerta as input and returns all Cantieri of the Cliente that is linked with the Offerta. these are the relationships: 
https://i.gyazo.com/490cd3085c412b7fcc91317d71705ee3.png

this is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Offerte.ID_offerta, Cantieri.ID_cantiere, Clienti.ID_Cliente
FROM Offerte,
     Cantieri,
     Clienti
WHERE (((Cantieri.ID_Cliente) = (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(Cantieri.ID_Cliente)
                                 FROM Cantieri,
                                      Offerte
                                 WHERE Offerte.ID_Cantiere = Cantieri.ID_Cantiere
                                   AND Offerte.ID_Offerta=[ins])));
```

and this is what i get: 
https://i.gyazo.com/7526cf11681c3828723e25cd24578c8d.png

thanks and sorry about the pizza and mandolino language

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a cartesian product between Offerte, Cantieri and Clienti

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Offerte.ID_offerta, Cantieri.ID_cantiere, Clienti.ID_Cliente
FROM Offerte,
     Cantieri,
     Clienti
WHERE (((Cantieri.ID_Cliente) = (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(Cantieri.ID_Cliente)
                                 FROM Cantieri,
                                      Offerte
                                 WHERE Offerte.ID_Cantiere = Cantieri.ID_Cantiere
                                   AND Offerte.ID_Offerta=[ins])))
AND Clienti.ID_Cliente = Cantieri.ID_Cliente
AND Offerte.ID_Offerta=[ins]
```

But from your initial description I'd go with this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Offerte.ID_offerta, Cantieri.ID_cantiere, Clienti.ID_Cliente
FROM Offerte,
     Cantieri,
     Clienti
WHERE Offerte.ID_Offerta=[ins]
AND Cantieri.ID_Cantiere = Offerte.ID_Cantiere
AND Clienti.ID_Cliente = Cantieri.ID_Cliente
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `INNER JOIN`!!!

```
SELECT o.ID_offerta, c.ID_cantiere, cl.ID_Cliente
FROM (Offerte as o INNER JOIN
      Cantieri as c
      ON o.ID_Cantiere = c.ID_Cantiere
     ) INNER JOIN
     Clienti as cl
     ON cl.ID_Cliente = c.ID_Cliente
WHERE o.ID_Offerta = [ins];
```

I removed the `DISTINCT`, because it is probably not necessary with the correct `JOIN`.  However, if it is still necessary, then include it.

You can probably simplify this query further by removing `Clienti`; the only column being used is already in `Cantiere`:

```
SELECT o.ID_offerta, c.ID_cantiere, c.ID_Cliente
FROM Offerte as o INNER JOIN
     Cantieri as c
     ON o.ID_Cantiere = c.ID_Cantiere
WHERE o.ID_Offerta = [ins];
```